What are the order-3 non-fractal irreptiles?
An irreptile is a shape that can be dissected into smaller copies of the same shape. An order-3 irreptile would divide into three similar copies of the original shape.
What are the order-3 non-fractal simply-connected irreptiles? I know about

Right triangles (infinite) and drafter3.
Four rectangles, which can be skewed to parallelograms.
An infinite set of quadrangles with two right angles and the tritan2.
The Vesa Timonen irregular pentagon.
Chairs by Mineyuki Uyematsu, Jun-ichi Miyoshi, Robert Ammann (and Karl Scherer) and Dale Walton.


Am I missing any non-fractal order-3 irreptiles? I have code for all of these at a community post.
I'd be interested in non-simply connected irreptiles for a separate item. An example:

Note, I'm not asking about fractal irreptiles, but I'd be interested in a
complete gallery with generators. Here are a few from IFSTile.


The 2-piece Ammann chair can also be split into 3 chairs in a different way.

All order-2 irreptiles are also order-3 irreptiles under this definition, but I assume you are interested in decompositions besides these ones.

Yes, but not many of those.  I include the right triangle, A4 paper and the Ammann Chair.
